# Плес - значение слова

Tags: значение-слов

Плес - это суша или вода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть и тем и другим.

В качестве суши плёс выступает когда имеется в виду береговая часть материка, образовавшаяся от завала реки землею или от изменения направления русла реки. Правда ныне в этом значении слово не используют, и нашёл я его только в Морском словаре 1941 года издания с пометой (арх).

В современном понимании плёс - это благоприятное для судоходства место в какой-либо акватории, как правило участок реки между двумя изгибами или перекатами, отличающийся спокойным течением и бо́льшими (чем на перекатах) глубиной и шириной.

Comment: Интересно... Я, наоборот, не знала, что плес - это глубокое место. Всегда считала, что это суша. Сочетание "песчаный плес" - часто встречается в художественных текстах. Да и в публицистических (о природе)тоже. Называть устаревшим как-то не хочется.

Answer (score 3):

В потамологии (науке о реках) есть понятие плесов и перекатов. Перекат — мелкое место, выступ дна, где течение всегда стремительное и быстрое. Плес — соответственно, глубокое место. Там вода гораздо более тихая и течение не так заметно.